# Не загружается стартовая страница Nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, azure

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня имеется сервер от Azure на Ubuntu 18.04, я установил на него ngnix, следуя данной [инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ubuntu-18-04-ru), но столкнулся с проблемой - при переходе по ip адресу сервера, ничего не загружается, хотя на сколько мне известно должна загрузиться стартовая страница nginx. При вводе команды `service nginx status` я получаю данный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Azureadmin@webmobubuntu:~$ service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-10-12 13:00:48 UTC; 1min 36s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 20208 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18213 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20223 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20211 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20224 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 2265)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─20224 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─20225 nginx: worker process
Oct 12 13:00:48 webmobubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 12 13:00:48 webmobubuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 12 13:00:48 webmobubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Oct 12 13:00:48 webmobubuntu systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

При вводе `sudo ufw status` получаю данный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Azureadmin@webmobubuntu:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: текст текстом пожалуйста ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor в плане вместо изображений ?

Comment: Я имею в виду код, ошибки, логи — все текстом, так удобно читать, можно копировать.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor оно здесь некорректно отображается, поэтому скрины сделал, сейчас исправлю описание

Comment: Да все нормально обозначается, ты просто внеси правок как получится, а я если че исправлю ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor исправил :)

Comment: и статус давай тоже...

Comment: статус чего? я извиняюсь, но не очень разбираюсь в Linux в целом, могу тупить

Comment: sudo ufw status

Comment: помимо "ничего не загружается" полезно было бы посмотреть почему именно не загружается, браузер обычно пишет какое какую диагностику проблемы. сообщение об ошибке несет кое какую полезную информацию. Еще можно глянуть а видел ли nginx запрос, скорее всего где то в /var/log/nginx